# how to get all indexes of removed data in list

Tags: java

How do I get a the indexes of all removed elements. When I have this list [a,a,b,b] and want to remove all the a. I use list.removeif(element -> element.contains("a"). Then I want the indexes in another list. I don't know how to get the indexes.

Comment: If the data was removed, it doesn't have indices any more. What exactly is the overall problem you are trying to solve? What will you do with those indices? If you want to remove corresponding elements from another list, then have you considered *structuring the data differently*?  I.e., so that the piece of information that should be considered together, are kept together?

Comment: I have another list. The element removed from that list will be the elements removed from this list. It is dependent.

Comment: @TheAlmightyBawan Having such dependent lists is usually a sign of an incorrect design, where instead of having multiple parallel lists of attributes, you should use a single lists with objects that contain those attributes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to remove first array value and same time remove second array value then you do this i hope it solve your issue.

```
     List<String> Array1 = new ArrayList<>();
    List<String> Array2 = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < Array1.size(); i++) {
        if (Array1.contains("a")) {
            Array1.remove(i);
            Array2.remove(i);
        }
    }
```

Comment: So I have this 2D list.[Button[id=exC, styleClass=button]'C']. How do I remove the first "[" and last "]" . I want it to look like this: Button[id=exC, styleClass=button]'C

Comment: Thank you it solved the problem

Comment: please upvote if solve your issue

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score. I am getting this

Comment: no problem thanks for this msg

Answer (score 0):

The elements from both list can be removed in reverse order

```
    List<String> list1 = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("a", "a", "b", "b"));
    List<String> list2 = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("A", "A", "B", "B"));

    for (int i = list1.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        if (list1.get(i).contains("a")) {
            list1.remove(i);
            list2.remove(i);
        }
    }
```